# use @2X for image

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

If i want to set an image for background of my app and use it on iphone3 i should use image with 320 * 480 resolution (image1.png)and for iphone 4 i should use image with 640 * 960 resolution(image2.png) how can i mange them?(means when should i use first image and when second image)

i read somewhere that i should use @2X but i can't understand how

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the name of the original image and then append `@2x` to the end of the 640*960 picture.

If your original is `Image.jpg` then your high-res picture should be `Image@2x.jpg`

Answer (score 3):

Load two resources into your project image.png (320x480) and image@2x.png (640x960). Whenever you need to specify an image just use image.png. During execution the application will automatically use the @2x image if the screen supports higher resolution. See [Loading Images into your Application](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/SupportingResolutionIndependence/SupportingResolutionIndependence.html).